# Passing date input when invoking via cxf jaxrs:client

Tags: java, cxf, jackson, jax-rs

Maybe this is really trivial, but somehow I have not been able to get around to finding why this doesn't work!

I have a service that is exposed via cxf's jaxrs:server directive

```
<jaxrs:server id="specialServiceRS"
    address="http://localhost:8080/specialServiceRS">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="specialService" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <bean id="jaxbProvider"
            class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JAXBElementProvider">
            <property name="marshallAsJaxbElement" value="true" />
            <property name="unmarshallAsJaxbElement" value="true" />
        </bean>
        <bean class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider">
            <property name="mapper" ref="jacksonMapper" />
        </bean>
        <bean class="com.kilo.ProgressiveDateHandler" />
    </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:server>
<bean id="jacksonMapper" class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper">
    <property name="serializationConfig.dateFormat">
        <bean class="java.text.SimpleDateFormat">
            <constructor-arg value="yyyyMMddHH:mm:ss.S" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="deserializationConfig.dateFormat">
        <bean class="java.text.SimpleDateFormat">
            <constructor-arg value="yyyyMMddHH:mm:ss.S" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

To be able to handle dates correctly, we added a date handler - [ProgressiveDateHandler](https://github.com/kilokahn/spring-testers/blob/master/spring-cxf-jaxrs-headless-tester/src/main/java/com/kilo/ProgressiveDateHandler.java) - which ParameterHandler and ParamConverter. This seems to work fine when invoked via the browser - however when invoked via a java based client configured via cxf's jaxrs:client directive,

```
<jaxrs:client id="specialServiceClient" serviceClass="com.kilo.SpecialServiceImpl"
    address="http://localhost:8080/specialServiceRS">
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <bean class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider">
            <property name="mapper" ref="jacksonMapper" />
        </bean>
        <bean class="com.kilo.ProgressiveDateHandler" />
    </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:client>
<bean id="jacksonMapper" class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper">
</bean>
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null value on 0 position
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.UriBuilderImpl.toStringList(UriBuilderImpl.java:767)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.UriBuilderImpl.queryParam(UriBuilderImpl.java:660)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.addMatrixOrQueryToBuilder(AbstractClient.java:671)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.convertMatrixOrQueryToBuilder(AbstractClient.java:661)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.addMatrixQueryParamsToBuilder(AbstractClient.java:638)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProxyImpl.handleQueries(ClientProxyImpl.java:432)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProxyImpl.invoke(ClientProxyImpl.java:162)
at org.apache.cxf.common.util.CglibProxyHelper$1.intercept(CglibProxyHelper.java:67)
at com.kilo.SpecialServiceImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$f5c4ae3f.getSomeStringsWithDateInput(<generated>)
at com.kilo.SpecialServiceJaxRSTest.testGetSomeStringsWithDateInput(SpecialServiceJaxRSTest.java:57)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:292)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

On further debugging, it looks like it is using the org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.ProviderFactory$LegacyParamConverter instead of my ParamConverter viz. ProgressiveDateHandler. Would really appreciate if someone could point out what is going wrong - mostly something I have configured incorrectly, because thisseems to be advertised as working out of the box when configuring the Handler.

Thanks in advance!

P.S.: I have a test [setup](https://github.com/kilokahn/spring-testers/blob/master/spring-cxf-jaxrs-headless-tester/src/test/java/com/kilo/SpecialServiceJaxRSTest.java#L54) if someone wants to see it in action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the correct way to use `ParamConverter` is also to implement the `ParamConverterProvider` interface as well as indicated [here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cxf/branches/2.7.x-fixes/rt/frontend/jaxrs/src/test/java/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/utils/JAXRSUtilsTest.java).

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public <T> ParamConverter<T> getConverter(Class<T> rawType,
        Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations) {
    if (rawType == Date.class) {
        return (ParamConverter<T>) this;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Not warming up to the concept of two interfaces helping in achieving the same thing as Sergey said on the jsr-339 mailing list - but you got to follow the specs! :)

That seems to get rid of the error - hope this helps someone else as well. 
Also, if I am taking a incorrect route, feel free to correct me. Thanks!